# Equivalence Relation on Prime Numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $P\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all primes. Let $\sim$ over $P$ be defined as
$p\sim q$ when for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$p+n\in P\Leftrightarrow q+n\in P.$$
I want to prove this  relation has an infinite number of equivalent classes.

Intuitively, I suspect that for every $p\in P$, $[p]=\{p\}$, otherwise we'd have two primes $p,q$ such that the sets of primes greater than each of them have the same patern, which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Unless you disqualify the completely trivial $p=q$, your proposition fails for $n=1$, as $p+n=2+1=3 \in P$ but there is no $q\ne p$ for which $q+1 \in P$. Similarly, you must disqualify $p=2$, as $2+n \in P$ has no corresponding $q+n \in P$.

Comment: @KeithBackman Which proposition fails? 

Let me understand. You say that for $p=2$ and $n=1$ you have that $p+n=3$ and that it's something exclusive for $p=2$. That would prove that $[2]=\{2\}$.

Comment: The proposition that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p+n\in P\Leftrightarrow q+n\in P$ fails unless $p=q$. You go on to indicate that for every $p\in P$, $[p]=\{p\}$ is a suspicion that you have. My comment was directed to your proposition, not your suspicion.

Comment: @KeithBackman If it fails for every $p,q$ such that $p\neq q$ then it holds that $[p]=\{p\}$. But how do you prove that?

Comment: When you start with $P$ including *all* primes and $n$ being *any* natural number, then the conclusion that $p=q$ is necessarily the case flows from a consideration of $n=1$ (actually, $n$ is any odd number) and $p=2$ because $2$ is the uniquely even prime. If you had started with $P$ being the set of all odd primes (i.e. excluding $2$), then the trivial objection would vanish, and you would move on to the proof in the answer provided by ajotatxe

Comment: @KeithBackman I don't start with $P$ and any $n$. I start with the set $P$. Then I define a relation $$\sim=\{(a,b)\in P\times P: (\forall n\in\mathbb{N}), a+n\in P \Leftrightarrow b+n\in P \}.$$

I mean the "$n$ being any natural number" is after I start defining $\sim$. As in "Let $\sim$ over $P$ be defined as 
$p\sim q$ when for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$..."

It's clear that $2\not\sim p$ for any $p\neq 2$ by the argument of $n=1$, but what you're saying doesn't follow.

Comment: @KeithBackman The issue in what you say is that you seem to be assuming that I'm saying that "for every $p,q\in P$, and every $n$, $p+n\in P \Leftrightarrow q+n\in P$". That's not what I'm saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classes are sigletons, indeed. By Dirichlet's theorem, for every two differenet primes $p$ and $q$ there is some positive integer $k$ such that $p+kq$ is prime, but certainly $q+kq$ is not prime.

Comment: Very nice. It's a very simple proof. The original problem was to prove that the language $\{0^p:p\text{ is prime}\}$ is not regular and that can be proven by using pumping lemma but I was wondering if there was a proof by using elementary number theory.

Comment: Sadly, the proof of Dirichlet's theorem is very far from 'simple'.  But I haven't use all the power of DT: it says some much stronger, but I don't know how to prove that there is a *single* prime of the form $p+kq$ without DT.

Comment: I see. Well, that's unfortunate. It's still really interesting.